# nanoc error on compilation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nanoc

I keep receiving this error on compilation all of a sudden! I upgraded ruby (ruby 2.0.0p195) and nanoc (3.6.4) but it did not resolve it.

> Macs-MacBook:folder mac$ nanoc  Loading site data…  Captain! We’ve
>   been hit!
>
> Message:
>
> ArgumentError: dump format error(0x32)
>
> Compilation stack:
>
> (empty)
>
> Stack trace:
>
> /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pstore.rb:475:in
>   `load'
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pstore.rb:475:in`
>   load'
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pstore.rb:410:in
>   `load_data'
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pstore.rb:327:in`
>   transaction'
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@folder/gems/nanoc-3.6.4/lib/nanoc/base/store.rb:76:in
>   `load'
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@folder/gems/nanoc-3.6.4/lib/nanoc/base/compilation/compiler.rb:127:in`
>   block in load'
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@folder/gems/nanoc-3.6.4/lib/nanoc/base/compilation/compiler.rb:127:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@folder/gems/nanoc-3.6.4/lib/nanoc/base/compilation/compiler.rb:127:in`
>   load'
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@folder/gems/nanoc-3.6.4/lib/nanoc/base/source_data/site.rb:250:in
>   `load'
>   /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@folder/gems/nanoc-3.6.4/lib/nanoc/cli/command_runner.rb:63:in`load_site' ... 22 more lines omitted. See full crash log for details.
>   If you believe this is a bug in nanoc, please do report it at
>   -> https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc/issues/new <-
>
> A detailed crash log has been written to ./crash.log.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug in nanoc being incompatible with Ruby 2.0?

Comment: the error appeared before updating nanoc and ruby.

Comment: Apparently [deleting the `/tmp` folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630761/nanoc-dump-format-error-while-compiling) in your site directory can resolve this problem.