# Dump format error while compiling site

Tags: compiler-errors, nanoc

When compiling my site in nanoc on the console, I'm receiving this error:

```
ArgumentError: dump format error for symbol(0x20).
```

Here's the full crash.log: http://pastebin.com/nrT0gwQh

What's causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Removing `tmp` will clear the error.

When I had the same issue, I realised that what I had done was a global find and replace on the entire nanoc directory, which changed a file in `/tmp`.  This is what caused the error - changing contents of the `tmp` directory with a tool outside `nanoc`